# When fetching questions using Stack Overflow API, the output is garbled

Tags: php, json, oauth, file-get-contents, stackexchange-api

I want to get some questions from Stack Overflow API. I have done the following things:

All the 3 steps executed successfully.

1. **Requested user to approve the app**: https://stackexchange.com/oauth/dialog?client_id=4783&scope=private_info&redirect_uri=https://stackexchange.com/oauth/login_success
2. **Get the access token from the user using this link**: https://stackexchange.com/oauth/login_success#access_token=..&expires=86399
3. **Go to the content page from where I have to get the data**: https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions?order=desc&sort=activity&site=stackoverflow&key=Z19xwkOfreckWgqMe7OiZg((&access_token=..

I am using

```
file_get_content("https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions?order=desc&sort=activity&site=stackoverflow&key=Z19xwkOfreckWgqMe7OiZg((&access_token=..")
```

to get data and print it. However data printed in browser I like this:

```
‹½\ýoÛ6·þWˆØ/oQõÕ‹bè×¶nëÚ5Ûºíâ" $ÊfbK®$Çñ†ýïï9¤äÈ±åHYwƒv$>Ç"ùø|3éF-ë³§ÿû×Y#gøæLÖ«óB5Tgªht³={rp‰r{qoØÿ=9+7…ªÎžþuV©Õº‘.‹³§‚‹'gëZU—:;{êA¸q{¥Ù®ÔÙS>Óu£*•¡Ü4U«æ²’ ÜŠÂ'g«ªÌõB]ê¥œáèyÓ¬ž:Ž>¯™^Ÿëål]§åÒñ~¯ëóU1ûª~æòèËÙ3äeº^-äö²KDX§sYÀõ….®ï¤YåªòE¹1Òðk§}^§²°¿ŸœéúRõÆ<íÓ\.jõäìF«ÍeZ®‹æìiS0÷»î“³:-+øpŸ*ëæR¦¾5»ÌÌ$]á¹A(Â i¥ÌºõoAä-TeºÙƒ1?±ŸÖª60\cqß½øá9v°Úé0Îf® ºÑ‹…:ßÎe=WÙJÖõ¦¬2Z©z½hh¢h½†ªëJáˆB©ÌìPaËüÄC~5b¾5bÞ·bˆCE.¬˜FÌVÌßOîèx%odVzÕ 7ŠÙz!««Þ—É•J›AÚ¹,èÑÎ½ÀFÓÎelïªúu­Î¯V'yWèëk²)‹ÙhêµÏì ’äöEgŸ{œ}¡ÜèÃ¼ÈãS†˜.f´þ´–•¢IÕÔT5¨*j7–®u»‚7*£My­Š¹~A    ÄJ b%Y+á)ùe'‚ülDÜ'îûJ¦s5H#Ïí±H„.‹„‚EÇ8SÃÂl6›óYŸØHËûÖÉx°HªLxaœ$øew}îJÎb•ÃÍ–QÙ3«fÓ²ø²zöþ›/óc»–ëÅ²,t=Í±vFN:‚d.4ËüøËxãxke<C7 Ø–uÇî+Í*TekMaº€ ‰.2¤Ÿ®ëµêQê¹N^ápòËb‡“v8±ÃÑ§ÈªRãÖÏ›å +d'¼»ªËõj˜X}^Eq    ï3òÊeqè'iæEcA–ñ8U¾¥a¤„'¹;‰W¯³åºÈÊñ¤²ÓqT‹»Ï¨¦Zß'”ÿy  ·Xà‰#†”ªïOT[ã˜í¤ê¶©ðI€BK°`zµPT-ÔVum€s5,mô²Ï¯ï.ÞýòžÜ¡I‡&ô4A41è>ÝÒÿümÞJ*+Š»(ef™–WZÍ×EjÈ5h¯O»À|¼MŒùtÆÂ˜¦i 3•ä" ?Î/¤‡< á!ßÊ+‘çê¥MC;=g‰P* tÝa&º0qÀ}½ÈCî›…WãÕM4®€qŽ1„¦r±À×{<¿Ë%]ªeŠqGž;Î¾ke‘ž¬§¤F¬0Òá #VØîâ…u‰n›^ÍË¿™ªõ¬ +ÙÝ ¼%«tñHÚ¬«aƒÌA¹ôU'¸ç,Íaw:‡ýØÏ£˜+ž‹+'BÉ4=æ‰ÍáDÅ¾áKÜÕÑºÔÌÏÙÃŽ±ÐÈÅEY«¬Ï6¢ï>¿ÙŽßô!‚ó£÷ã0òã;PÃB„ÑT5ŒXAÜ¥   ±•«Ý#Înâð¤52vöû–”+] ñYïE+úÝ¡äÃXò|µ"ÏûbûLž•åô>~´*fÚÐyVRÖDo;ÆF~ Ø)[¿ÏX1±Ryà? éyIŠV‚à‚ºe“"ËÊCÆþ¬—ËÑLµórÄŒ`¨8¡h2ùÇ"Wø¡ïñð]pÁÃûŠ–¢iqr‡q*´(P«ÎþÔÀ¯`Ä4e¦UMg{éÈö¡C’o,’tHb‘´)òïµEñ:—Ûú:›WY’âKRÖõ°Õß÷4#óái.æþ¹å=B3 pÇ,½Üpþâí7¿mKç»Ÿ7»÷/âçÎíïl…¾Ì³&rÀ4¥—ÿD&ï×+²˜ânâœœ›+º¥œM6–y"0ñÜw½a ˆ°CÏÝp²‰Œ3Sñ?+xvp©ª*°÷›9ìmª-ÞjJ ;T`m¨b-}KžŽ‡ßX9¤•CŒbä+‡4%iå#Çy#gÏ9ýÄnV¹ÙHcøe…yCu›.Ö™á~   jªÈ¾†ÌsGç‡s5 Wóó\¦*)Ëk³ .ÃŸ,ƒÂ•6úý+ü˜gYÍÔ!¿WÅ—_xñÿh°ä­lêõV.åx‚Úù8×ª@    t¹“ð°?ê¨I>ÖCþ¨`ÑýPÛ+§0NJíF#ó0»W[ºíQ¡#ÝË/Èn01ƒ-§zƒ‡³WòÖdl0ØªÅpp½¯òRoÅ@¢’õê–®`]¢±™WŠûÙöŠô(‚8‚8T9ˆ#ˆ3:ÅââÚ‘ƒòÔ¸|‹"÷s6Äye\æaœ¡ÏÝ˜³Œå^Kæå“¬×«íBäÕ„d‚™Ž“!Žfÿ4JÅ:^CB†5CTïH LvÌM5oA`jHàÔ¤à>£-S· +=›7¶-„nh:Ÿ¹Vð*±`u¯Zô²ƒ„·m"dã—¯;ü¾o»FÆðÍã>NŸ3ôÃÄõ7Qiœ†~¥A&O²„‰ÌÄ´ü>Uûˆã}&;ÞécGð.~´ÚâM"Šã©Ðxj“ˆÁÇ)…ïö¡ß”ma™t ~J…ÙQ‰“Îh™Ã+ÒÜp/× lž.è]3Qßwy’Ðujå+\{“‘2‡××­<ò5ÊÃÔC'ï~ú¡g»J’É­zM}õçîyS+HC¹xÎh˜’"£²ñä&sY\OˆÛÇvàë{Ó‚ÇøP'Â@Ê`ÝPµâ“hX×ñ£Õ¢ ˜î`Æýîj@åº¢@ˆÍ`—iR‚M-WVÖja[-oäbÏyxWú8ypò àäEyKÞ·prÑÂÉ¯Þç›ºMì&‘¶"¤ßr­ß-î‰ØýÑíþ@%è”2Lcá†^¬”HóÜWqÇLº™RótehŸy¼2´ã>ö_MOð¡¬½u,=!‘žN½Nl®–ëu^%‹YW¯„ø±@åW•›Ý.:ª5iK“%þˆúí@UZ ZE›4›åðp\_›yœyâ”qÝÏMøÓÔ[ÀBæ3ß¥×. Pö±ãd¼V³ïÔÅ p3*³*þ?©ã=‚:°^˜n0ûˆþ?6U®*u£ËuM7*1¡ØK»ñwðp1ôý±•²Ãƒ61Ç\1$Ðr3KôÂžz¹Q‹2=u²å^c…‡Ÿ3* ½ÿ,U±çJÆ„.¼œI/á®ê<®˜ÞÊÊªáÑ-8giaÿj¶žEöÖ1N=âÜAÀ Œj·”v{½g_7ó#ž×›šüÚŽ&w£   Žîüª¯ŽµæÈ50÷C¶Ý”%^ÁU]òöEGšœ‹~‹®çGÂ;Åª=õä!NÒ,,L¡| –ç&2ðUùIœ—¹q<±˜]5sNÈžšù9;ÜÃ Ý£GvD¸Gò§^€d7éŸ!‡ìàø‹ë‡üI¹ÕãlÚÔ)"7ÊJÿiÉd70‚Ð ÖtòÖ hl•»cÑÝù*›3ýxñŽ“=)&×RˆnLÓJMv¢l ü?ÊÝ«[xæ•ÊGUÃEÄc}Îc"ÌRž0X§ÌOC€ös3È)ü©:¯(¯&–‹Ú)âìøZÑABm´ös›tÂã µèq`º”¾é›€ÙÁ~d4Qª.BÒªMòÛbâbkyW”ÕR.(r‚.lãò½¼>J$­D‚‰•HÀc³™þN¢¥Ÿ•HP"A‰G’û»è´=xŠj3ÍÍYu*m²—Û½Ð GçpƒGÄ9…LÐ“‘ÏÝ(æyî±ˆG2SÆ²ñÇd­s¢?%r¼‰n§ç ”Zè£Z7Æ3Õê}ŒÙ)åéÍÜ¹Óó+€qÒuÝ+Á™3‡¸ jAí™B ‰9ç¥S›)úPKŸ]û™Á‹Gwð;ƒ'O>¾üš´x£E;úíÔT¨ä#¥l*=œ7ñú5çÜS|œ\õôî¡ïù*ô„âYú>cH9D¯rZÞøy•©e²ØŽW•v>Žì€Ûn4²Ìà ²O°Þ#¼DÀ8•Ô†K’r n´©@Ðö¯"ãÒ~+·L$á¯ˆlÊÄFz½Ü5–òO0ót4Eeez­ÐDÙÛæÃIa¼ÔucÏxá*­PÄŒ›ºË#š¼ÅP“÷þw?¼ø¤çÁo›£MÞÏ_¼v~ú)Ò¼ò·?æõˆ&ïodµ%ï!^›pÆÎÌ™”BÿYlòÐ‘w8àuÞéw<®j·×œ°$QiM[ôõ{wa˜aäõËÒ ;–v«Ëª9U¿Ï|ÎJCêgR²”{±÷—'R€‡—»,Ëc°˜¡?IC}/‹Ù|»†/Õ¼ °„MSD?¦ÚÀÇ³† UÏ‹»…8Ö.Æä *bœvçi±Æ#yæpª¤3½A%¨l£Ë:–tôj1¤Å˜1b0xÁbîwÏ>1•×Y¥NµÒF{Evî‡~p’nÿà2¸•¿Nª²ÿ ÊbBV¤}`gaaÿêÿaƒ=dŒ Ÿ4ìhsFðˆæÀ89| \¤kïv‚[´?9zô}/ëk‹#kß[ÜÅO?W-Î¸W_[Ü‘@ö¨\7¦›ñFæ·»7ÍÖ¸6•\­Néµ Ú¥MlÄ‹ødÕj¿¡ã=hi+žò< #<GJd¾ë',vU–«ÑÁÀÌ.8Uã#;7§Ã<|—àÛí¥\¶ÌDê´×ÌÊúŽZœ‡±ÏÈ<:t`Çƒ\ÁÃS'£ƒàþù­(ð'v}[Œ³‚€SU°"]­ßaÑÇ©Ê­¯ÑµÃÔ…uÿÅ`ôB&{:ò}'§+ú›âk+‡ r'î´rˆ•ó7v.ëË¥Y7ë"Z—¼\Ê[³ö+ŒW*µ´RÀÅ±ÿ÷£¼ø®I
```

How can I retrieve the page data. This data is not in JSON form.

Comment: Is the data Gzipped?

Comment: I found the answer. It is in zipped form. Just used this

$json=file_get_contents("https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions?order=desc&sort=activity&site=stackoverflow&key=Z19xwkOfreckWgqMe7OiZg((&access_token=****");
$json_data = json_decode(gzdecode($json), true);

Answer (score 0):

For future reference, @sachinmanit found answer to his question as mentioned in the comment. I’ve copied it here for clarity:

The response is in Gzipped, so the response needs to be extracted in order to read it. The way @sachinmanit handled it is following:

```
$json = file_get_contents("api.stackexchange.com/2.2/…");
$json_data = json_decode(gzdecode($json), true);
```